# Retrieving sandbox details

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

Which API can I use to find out the last refresh date of the current sandbox?

Does Salesforce have an API available to find out the sandbox details? I would like to find out the last refresh date, sandbox type, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no api to query that. You can only see that in company information details page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to find the Sandbox details. However, you can check the 'LastModifiedDate' field to check when your Sandbox was last refreshed.

```
SELECT Id, Name, InstanceName, IsSandbox, LastModifiedDate, OrganizationType FROM Organization
```